# What should i do to load DicomImage using Imageio JAI?

Tags: java, image, dicom

I am developing application to load Dicom image in netbeans platform....i developed the apps but its give me null pointer exception..so is there any jsr api missing or plugins ,,i havnt get where i am wrong..i added the source code  plz share your ideas here

```
             package org.netbeans.GuiImage;


            import com.sun.media.jai.widget.DisplayJAI;
            import java.awt.Dimension;
            import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
            import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
            import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
            import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
            import java.awt.image.renderable.ParameterBlock;
            import java.io.File;
            import java.io.FileInputStream;
            import java.io.FileOutputStream;
            import java.util.Iterator;
            import javax.imageio.*;
            import javax.imageio.stream.FileImageInputStream;
            import javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream;
            import javax.media.jai.JAI;
            import javax.media.jai.PlanarImage;
            import javax.media.jai.RenderedOp;
            import javax.swing.*;
            import org.netbeans.api.settings.ConvertAsProperties;
            import org.openide.awt.ActionID;
            import org.openide.awt.ActionReference;
            import org.openide.util.NbBundle;
            import org.openide.windows.TopComponent;
            import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
            import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;


            @ConvertAsProperties(dtd = "-//org.netbeans.guiimage//run//EN",autostore = true)
            @TopComponent.Description(preferredID = "run",
            persistenceType = TopComponent.PERSISTENCE_ALWAYS)
            @TopComponent.Registration(mode = "editor", openAtStartup = true)
            @ActionID(category = "Window", id = "org.netbeans.guiimage.run")
            @ActionReference(path = "Menu/Window" /*
            * , position = 333
            */)
            @TopComponent.OpenActionRegistration(displayName = "#CTL_runAction",
            preferredID = "run")

            public final class run extends TopComponent implements ActionListener{

                private JPanel jPanel1 = new JPanel();
                private JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();
                private JTabbedPane jtp=new JTabbedPane();
                private ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("E:/tif/v1.TIF");
                private JFrame jFrame1 = new JFrame();
                private JButton jButton1 = new JButton("open");
                private JButton jButton2 = new JButton("save");
                private JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
                private File filePath = new File("E:/Images/Image1.png");
                private String filename;
                private BufferedImage bi=null;
                private FileInputStream fis;
                private FileOutputStream fos;
                private FileImageOutputStream fios;
            int retVal;
            private RenderedImage image=null;
            private ImageReader reader;
            private FileImageInputStream fiis;
            private Iterator iter , witer;
            private RenderedOp result=null;
            private ImageWriter writer;
            private DisplayJAI djai;
            private JScrollPane jsp;
            // private DicomFileDialog dicomFileDialog;




                //private FileImageInputstream fiis = new FileImageInputStream(filePath);
                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                    "png,dcm Images", "dcm", "png");


                public run(){
                    initComponents();
                    setName(NbBundle.getMessage(run.class,"CTL_run"));
                    setToolTipText(NbBundle.getMessage(run.class, "HINT_run"));
                }



                private void initComponents() {

                    jsp.add(jButton1);
                    jsp.add(jButton2);
                    jButton1.addActionListener(this);
                    jsp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));



                    javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame1.getContentPane());
                    jFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame1Layout);
                    jFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE));
                    jFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
                            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE));
                    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
                    this.setLayout(layout);
                    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(jsp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE));
                    layout.setVerticalGroup(
                            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(jsp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE));
                }




                @Override
                public void componentOpened() {

                }

                @Override
                public void componentClosed() {

                }

                void readProperties(java.util.Properties p) {
                // do the read
            }
            void writeProperties(java.util.Properties p) {
                // handle the store
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if(e.getSource() == jButton1){
                        //Add a custom file filter and disable the default
                        //(Accept All) file filter.
                        jfc.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileFilter() {

                @Override
                public boolean accept(File filePath) {
                        if (filePath.isDirectory()) {
                        return (true);
                    }
                    String extension = Utils.getExtension(filePath);
                    if (extension != null) {
                        if (extension.equals(Utils.dicom)
                                || extension.equals(Utils.dcm)
                                || extension.equals(Utils.dic)
                                || extension.equals(Utils.tif)) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public String getDescription() {
                    return "*.dcm,"              
                        + "*.dicom,"
                        + "*.TIF,"
                        +"*.tif,"
                        + "*.dic";
                }
            });
                        jfc.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);



                        int retVal = jfc.showOpenDialog(this);

                        System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());

                        if(retVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){

                                filePath = jfc.getSelectedFile();

                                filename = filePath.getName();




                                System.out.println("Selected file:");
                                System.out.println(filename);



                    try {
                        fiis = new FileImageInputStream(new File(filename));
                        iter = ImageIO.getImageReaders(fiis);
                        reader = (ImageReader) iter.next();

                        reader.setInput(fiis);
                        image = reader.readAsRenderedImage(0, reader.getDefaultReadParam());

                        double scaleFactor = 0.5;
                        ParameterBlock params = new ParameterBlock();
                        params.addSource(image);
                        params.add(scaleFactor);


                        result = JAI.create("", params);


                        witer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("DICOM");
                        writer = (ImageWriter) witer.next();
                        fios = new FileImageOutputStream(new File(filename));
                        writer.setOutput(fios);
                        writer.write(result);
                        djai.set(result);
                        jsp.setViewportView(djai);
                       }
            catch(Exception ex){
                //error dialog - invalid file type
                System.out.println("Invalid file type, please try again");

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File Not Recognized", "Error!",  JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        else if(retVal == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION){
            System.out.println("User cancelled operation");
        }}

    private void setResizable(boolean b) {
     throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
   }
         }
```

Comment: post the error showing which line gave you the NPE

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that ImageIO has a reader/writer for dicom ?
I know it's not supported directly by the JDK, so did you write or use any SPI ?

I'd bet that ImageIO.getReaderFormatNames() doesn't list dicom.

So to actually load your dicom image, you'll either have to write/find an image spi (see the javadoc for [ImageIO.scanForPlugins](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#scanForPlugins%28%29) for more info), or use another api, like the one provided by [pixelmed](http://www.pixelmed.com/).

Edit: upon closer inspection, it looks like dcm4che does provide a SPI. You need the dcm4che-imageio-XXX.jar file in yout classpath.

Comment: @ Vfiack,,,thanks for raplying ...but i dont want to use any plugins so it should be possible???

Comment: @Josek   thanks to replyinig ,,,but can u tell me that for loading dicom image is that any plugins or jar api needed??